# The 'MSDAORA.1' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, iis

I have an application that connects to a DB, extracts info, creates a excel file, and then drops the file/emails X people the file.

The application was created in Visual Studios using .NET 2.0 Framework (Windows Form App). It was run on a 32 bit server. But it recently was moved to a 64 bit server. It is now returning with the error message " The 'MSDAORA.1' provider is not registered on the local machine."

I believe that MSDAORA is only supported for 32-bit applications and the Application Pool the app runs under in IIS is not enabled for 32-bit applications.

How would I fix this issue, is there something I can change in IIS? Or is it a code change?

Comment: Windows Form App and IIS/application pool?

Comment: I was not sure if it connects to it as well. It runs as an executable so there is interaction with the form.

Comment: Windows executable doesn't use IIS application pool. But in any case consider using providers from Oracle itself it has both 32 and 64 bit versions

Comment: Woul replaceing it with "OraOLEDB.Oracle" do the trick?

Comment: You have to have correct driver installed. Also connection string might be different, check out docs for Oracle driver and www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the solutions for this. The problem stemmed from running the machine on a 64bit machine. To change that in VS, open up the properties page of the solution and in the build tab change the targeted platform to x86. And that did the trick.

http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/

Thanks for your help Yuriy.

Answer (score 6):

Using `ORAOLEDB.ORACLE` rather than `MSDAORA` fixed the same issue for me - changing the platform target from 'Any CPU' to 'X86' caused errors within my project in Visual Studio.

See answer [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1022162)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but I used another solution because my application is running in IIS.

In the *advanced settings* of the application pool I changed the value for `Enable 32-Bit Applications` to **true**.

Answer (score 1):

I had he same issue but it wasn't 32/64bit. I used the ODAC xcopy installer and forgot to run it in a cmd.exe **as administrator**. It didn't give any error so I had a hard time figuring this out. The xcopy part worked but the DLL registration via regsvr32 silently failed.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15

11/08/2018

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Windows. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature. Instead, use Oracle's OLE DB provider.

so probably using ORAOLEDB.ORACLE is the correct solution, but that seems like more effort than just changing the connection string.