# Showing information in the datagrid from the table in the oracle database using C#

Tags: c#, oracle, datagridview

I'm experiencing a problem here, I have connected the sql database with C# successfully but when I try to show the data from the table to the datagridview it gives me this error:

"The 'MSDAORA' provider is not registered on the local machine."

Okay I understood that MSDAORA it's working only on the 32bit system and mine is 64bit, on the internet they said I  should use "ORAOLEDB.ORACLE" and it still gives me the same error message.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using the `ORAOLEDB.ORACLE` NameSpace what ever that client maybe correctly..also the machine you are running it from do you have that .dll references / registered and or GAC'd did you reference this properly is there an entry in the .cofig file etc..

Comment: possible duplicate of [The 'MSDAORA.1' provider is not registered on the local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844383/the-msdaora-1-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Comment: DJ KRAZE I don't know anything about any of .dll references and .config file. Where and how can I get them? Krekkon yeah I also had that error.