# Oracle connection string provider error from OraOLEDB.Oracle to MSDAORA.1

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, connection-string, oledb, ora-01017

When I change my Oracle connectionstring provider from  **"OraOLEDB.Oracle"** to **"MSDAORA.1"**
it's not connecting and giving **"ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied" error.**

For example:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=XXX;User ID=YYY;Password=ZZZ; => connecting 

Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=XXX;User ID=YYY;Password=ZZZ; => ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

I read old articles about ORA-01017 errors in this forum.

- I tried change sqlnet.ora "ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION_SERVER" parametr.
- I set SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON= false.

But still not connecting
What is the problem?

[Sample Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fTIo.png)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/19866845/413032